# What is the best rational approximation of $\frac{1}{x}$

Tags: approximation, rational-numbers

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $x \notin \mathbb{Q}$ and let the function $f:\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q} \,\times \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ provide the best rational approximation for $x$ where the denominator is less than or equal to a given number $N \in \mathbb{N}$. E.g. $f(\pi, 50) = \frac{22}{7}$.

Let $f(x, N) = \frac{a}{b} > 0$, is it possible to prove that $f(\frac{1}{x}, a) = \frac{b}{a}$? Is it even perhaps possible to identify $M > a$ and make the stronger statement that $f(\frac{1}{x}, M) = \frac{b}{a}$?

Would appreciate suggestions on a good approach to take.

Comment: I don't have time to think about a complete answer right now, but check out continued fraction expansions. From the wikipedia article: "[...] The simple continued fraction for x generates all of the best rational approximations for x [...]", see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction

Comment: @cdwe, thanks, I will have a read.

Comment: I changed the question to restrict $x$ to the irrationals.

Comment: I don't see how this is well-defined.  Could you be a bit more precise about your terminology?  What qualifies as "best rational approximation for $x$"?  As far as I can tell, $201/64$ is a better approximation of $\pi$, and the denominator is less than $100$.  Better yet, why not $311/99$?

Comment: Even if you restrict $f$ to the irrationals, the proposal is false. Take an irrational number $x$ close enough to $1/3$, and you'll still have $f(x, 2) = 1/2$ and $f(1/x, 1) = 3$.

Comment: Namely, any irrational $2/7 < x < 2/5$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: It's possible that Paul means $22/7$ is a [better rational approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation#Best_Diophantine_approximations_of_a_real_number) of $\pi$ than $201/64$ is in the sense that $|22 - 7\pi| < |201 - 64\pi|$. (If so, Paul, you should add this definition to the question.)

Comment: $f(\pi,100)\ne 22/7$..........$3+14/99$ is much closer to $\pi$ than $3+1/7$ is.

Comment: Thanks @DanielWainfleet, I've changed the example to $f(\pi, 50) = 22/7$.

Comment: Thanks @SimplyBeautifulArt, I've changed the example.

Comment: @Rahul, thanks for the link. I had only considered 'best' in the sense given by Simply Beautiful Art, I think I need to revisit this question taking the information in the link into account.

Comment: @lulu what if we added the restriction that $x>1$, i.e. that $a > b$?

Comment: I don't think it helps. I'm doing it quickly, but I think $f(\frac 53, 2)=\frac 32$ but $f(\frac 35,5)=\frac 35$.

Comment: I make $f(\frac{5}{3}, 2) = \frac{2}{1}$, if the definition of the best approximation minimises $|b x - a|$. And then $f( \frac{3}{5} , 2) = \frac{1}{2}$. I.e. as per previous comments, the measure that defines best seems to be key.

Comment: We can give a "Yes" using the theory of Farey sequences.